# My text-decoration (underline) isn't showing on mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I have a list of links that I've manually underlined (not using the default link underline). It works on the chrome devtools mobile preview, but when I deploy and view on an actual mobile device, the underline's aren't there.

I've used inline styles as well as css, and I've tried adding !important to the underline styles.

in the .js file

```
<Link  className="BigNames-link" to='/Adobe' style={{textDecoration:'none'}}>
                    <span style={{textDecoration: 'underline #101010  !important'}} className='Name'>Adobe Creative Cloud</span>
                    <span style={{textDecoration: 'underline #101010  !important'}} className='Text'>: App Banner</span>  <img src={Lock} alt="..."className="Lock"></img>
                </Link>
                <Link className="BigNames-link" to='/Wacom'>
                    <span style={{textDecoration: 'underline #101010  !important'}} className='Name'>Wacom</span>
                    <span style={{textDecoration: 'underline #101010  !important'}} className='Text'>: Product Launch Emails</span>  <img src={Lock} alt="..."className="Lock"></img>
                </Link>
```

in the css file

```
.BigNames span{
    text-decoration: underline #101010  !important;
}
```

Again, it works exactly how I want it. It looks like it should work according to devtools "mobile" views. It simply isn't showing an underline on any of the links on mobile devices.

Comment: is the css file maybe cached?

Comment: Does it work without the color?

Answer (score 0):

Because you give wrong class. You use .BigNames class instead of BigNames-link class. 
Try This:

```
.Name, .Text{
text-decoration: underline #101010  !important;
}
```